# Word2008 for MAc - track changes appear in miniscule fontsize when sharing with PC users

Tags: microsoft-word

Word2008 for MAc - track changes balloons appear in miniscule fontsize when sharing with PC users (in both directions!)- how to change this to a readable font?

Answer (score 1):

The size of text in comment balloons can be changed via the Styles menu. Look for "Balloon Text" in your document styles list and increase its font size.

The Balloon Text style is based on Normal, and there is where I believe your real issue lies. Perhaps the document's Normal was edited in some way to force a specific font size.

The root of this issue is the fundamental font-rendering distinction between Macs and PCs: Macs measure fonts with *points* while PCs measure fonts with *pixels*. It is a headache that often crops up in email, when users of Outlook are sent messages with impossibly small font sizes.